# Exposing public webhook URL for inspecting events

Tags: api, webhooks

We have to explain how webhooks are working on our developer portal.
To provide interactive examples on our sandbox, entitled users can launch processes that will trigger
an event to be generated and sent.

For simplicity and better understanding, we would like to share a public URL where all
those sent event can be futher seen (read-only mode).

We found webhook.site which is great but not stable over time in its free version.

Do you know any simple way to achieve this?
We seek something simple and stable over time (url not changing after X events or given period)

thks

Answer (score 0):

Try Svix Play: https://www.svix.com/play/.

Does the same as webhook.site but the URL persists. We're also in the process of releasing the Play API to the public.